# Union and Cartesian Product Illustration

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I illustrate $A\times (B\cup C)$ and $(A\times B)\cup (A\times C)$? I have proved that they are equal but now require to prove it with an illustration? I am struggling!

Comment: You go back to whomever it was that told you to "prove" with an illustration, and you demand your money back!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
           -----C---
   -----B-----
|  x x x x x x x x x
|  x x x x x x x x x
A  x x x x x x x x x
|  x x x x x x x x x
|  x x x x x x x x x
```

Comment: Thankyou, how can does the image show that Ax(BUC) = (AxB)U(AxC) is true though?